# Postgres connection error when deploying on Heroku

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, sqlalchemy, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to deploy my Django Dash app on Heroku; the build succeeds, but I get the following error:

```
(psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

Everything works locally.

My database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'datanz',
        'USER': 'xxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500, ssl_require=True)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

And establishing the connection and getting the database configuration:

```
heroku_app_name = "datanz"
raw_db_url = subprocess.run(
    ["heroku", "config:get", "DATABASE_URL", "--app", heroku_app_name],
    capture_output=True, shell=True
).stdout 

db_url = raw_db_url.decode("ascii").strip()

# Convert "postgres://<db_address>"  --> "postgresql+psycopg2://<db_address>" needed for SQLAlchemy
final_db_url = "postgresql+psycopg2://" + db_url.lstrip("postgres://") + "?sslmode=require"

# Create SQLAlchemy engine
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(final_db_url)

df1=pd.read_sql_query(sql, con=engine)   #example of my connections
```

I'm using the free Heroku version. Could this be the issue?

Full traceback:

```
Environment:
Django Version: 3.2.3
Python Version: 3.9.12

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3280, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 310, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 868, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 476, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 371, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 666, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 590, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 597, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)

The above exception (connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 167, in _get_response
    callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = self.resolve_request(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 290, in resolve_request
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 556, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
    <source code not available>
  File "/app/datasite/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/app/datasite/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from data.dash_lab import ur_latest
  File "/app/data/dash_lab.py", line 26, in <module>
    df1=pd.read_sql_query(statement_df1, con=engine)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 399, in read_sql_query
    return pandas_sql.read_query(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1557, in read_query
    result = self.execute(*args)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1402, in execute
    return self.connectable.execution_options().execute(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 2, in execute
    <source code not available>
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 401, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3175, in execute
    connection = self.connect(close_with_result=True)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3234, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3313, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3283, in _wrap_pool_connect
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2117, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3280, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 310, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 868, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 476, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 371, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 666, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 590, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 597, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /
Exception Value: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Comment: Heroku's free plan is open for 16 hours a day, and if you don't connect for 30 minutes, the initial loading time will be longer when you enter sleep mode and wake up from sleep mode.

Comment: Why are you doing any of that "establishing the connection" junk? `dj_database_url` should take care of that itself. You don't need to run `heroku config:get` (and it will likely fail since the Heroku CLI is not installed on dynos), just use the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable (this is what `dj_database_url` does for you). Also, why are you using SQLAlchemy when you already have Django and its ORM?

Comment: "I'm using the free Heroku version. Could this be the issue?"—no, that's irrelevant. This is a configuration issue.

Comment: @Chris Thanks. The "junk" was my best effort to get this to work, was following a tutorial. It seems to work though, in that it puts the data in the database on Heroku. SQLAlchemy seemed to make the most sense for my case, but could be wrong of course. Though I can't really restructure my project now at this late stage (and is running well locally). Will try what you suggest re `DATABASE_URL` and see if that solves it.

Comment: @Chris That didn't solve it. Any other ideas of what can be causing my issue? Thanks.

Comment: "It seems to work though, in that it puts the data in the database on Heroku"—I'm confused. Isn't the whole problem that your app _cannot_ connect to the database on Heroku? The error message you show indicates that your application is trying to connect to a database on the local machine.

Comment: @Chris I know, it's weird, but the data is there (on Heroku postgres), so it must have worked? But I'm not able to open the app on Heroku due to the Operational Error.

Comment: @Chris When running local server, connection with heroku postgres is made (and the data is uploaded/updated), but then the error occurs after deploying and attempting to open the app. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Chris was correct. The `heroku config:get` commands failed and therefore I couldn't get the correct database details. I solved it by using `dj_database_url` and then getting the necessary variables from there, like this:

```
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(default=DATABASES['default'], conn_max_age=500, ssl_require=True)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
db_engine = DATABASES['default']['ENGINE']
db_name = DATABASES['default']['NAME']
db_user = DATABASES['default']['USER']
db_password = DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']
db_host = DATABASES['default']['HOST']
db_port = DATABASES['default']['PORT']
ENGINE = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://"+db_user+":"+db_password+"@"+db_host+":"+str(db_port)+"/"+db_name)
```